# How do you comment on an RFC?

Tags: oauth, rfc

I have some comments about the [OAuth draft RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-hammer-oauth-10) (specifically about some errors it contains), but I'm not sure what the accepted way is to make them.

There's an email address at the bottom, so do I simply send mail there with the comments, or is there some IETF tool I should know about for tracking comments/issues?

Comment: Whoever voted to close this as off topic... how on earth can you believe that commenting on an RFC is not programming related? Do you even know what an RFC is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [OAuth mailing list](https://www.ietf.org/mailman/listinfo/oauth) would be my first guess. I found this through the IETF home page.

Comment: With all due respect, I'm not really looking for a guess, I'm looking for feedback from people familiar with the process. I know that people involved in the RFC process can be very particular and picky, and I don't want to start off on the wrong foot.

Comment: Nevertheless, Thomas' answer is right (and I know the IETF, even if I never wrote a RFC myself). On the working group mailing list, you will find everyone (including the authors).

Since this particular document has already been accepted by IESG, and will soon be published at a RFC, it may be safer to copy your comments to the RFC editor rfc-editor@rfc-editor.org to minimize the risk of the publication of a faulty document.

Comment: @borzmeyer - OK thanks, I'll do both. @Thomas - good guess, thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

The best late-process way to report an error is indeed to use the email address at the bottom of the document, and contact the author directory.  Early stage discussions take place on mailing lists.  Errors can (sometimes) be handled with errata to the RFC.